# Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") Error Class Not Found

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
private void jAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        String url="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/One";
        String username = "one1";
        String password = "matt123";

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
        String Query = " INSERT INTO ONE (NAME ,SURNAME) ('"+jName.getText()+"','"+jModel.getText()+"')";
    } catch(SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.toString());
    }   // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

Comment: first write your question in a proper way , second add the libraries to your classpath before starting the java application

Answer (score 3):

The problem is **MySQL driver is missing** in your project's classpath.

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.16/mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar copy and paste the jar file in your `classpath`. If it is a web-application copy and paste the jar file in `WEB-INF/lib/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

It is what it is; the class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` can't be found by your classloader, meaning you probably forgot to include the JAR in your classpath.